# Dataflow's BigQuery inserter thread pool exhausted

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm using Dataflow to write data into BigQuery.

When the volume gets big and after some time, I get this error from Dataflow:

```
{
 metadata: {
  severity: "ERROR"    
  projectId: "[...]"    
  serviceName: "dataflow.googleapis.com"    
  region: "us-east1-d"    
  labels: {…}    
  timestamp: "2016-08-19T06:39:54.492Z"    
  projectNumber: "[...]"    
 }
 insertId: "[...]"   
 log: "dataflow.googleapis.com/worker"   
 structPayload: {
  message: "Uncaught exception: "    
  work: "[...]"    
  thread: "46"    
  worker: "[...]-08180915-7f04-harness-jv7y"    
  exception: "java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@1a1680f rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@b11a8a1[Shutting down, pool size = 100, active threads = 100, queued tasks = 2316, completed tasks = 1192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2047)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1369)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.submit(Executors.java:681)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.BigQueryTableInserter.insertAll(BigQueryTableInserter.java:218)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.BigQueryIO$StreamingWriteFn.flushRows(BigQueryIO.java:2155)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.io.BigQueryIO$StreamingWriteFn.finishBundle(BigQueryIO.java:2113)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.finishBundle(DoFnRunnerBase.java:158)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.finishBundle(SimpleParDoFn.java:196)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.finishBundle(ForwardingParDoFn.java:47)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.finish(ParDoOperation.java:62)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:79)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:657)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$500(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:86)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:483)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)"    
  logger: "com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker"    
  stage: "F10"    
  job: "[...]"    
 }
}
```

It looks like I'm exhausting the thread pool defined in [BigQueryTableInserter.java:84](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/util/BigQueryTableInserter.java#L84). This thread pool has an hardcoded size of 100 threads and cannot be configured.

My questions are:

- How could I avoid this error?
- Am I doing something wrong?
- Shouldn't the pool size be configurable? How can 100 threads be the perfect fit for all needs and machine types?

Here's a bit of context of my usage:

- I'm using Dataflow in streaming mode, reading from Kafka using [KafkaIO.java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/contrib/kafka/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/contrib/kafka/KafkaIO.java)
- "After some time" is a few hours, (less than 12h)
- I'm using 36 workers of type n1-standard-4
- I'm reading around 180k messages/s from Kafka (about 130MB/s of network input to my workers)
- Messages are grouped together, outputting around 7k messages/s into BigQuery
- Dataflow workers are in the us-east1-d zone, BigQuery dataset location is US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong, though you may need more resources, depending on how long volume stays high.

The streaming `BigQueryIO` write does some basic batching of inserts by [data size and row count](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/util/BigQueryTableInserter.java#L64). If I understand your numbers correctly, your rows are large enough that each is being submitted to BigQuery in its own request.

It seems that the thread pool for inserts should install [`ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy.html) which causes the caller to block and run jobs synchronously when they exceed the capacity of the executor. I've posted [PR #393](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/pull/393). This will convert the work queue overflow into pipeline backlog as all the processing threads block.

At this point, the issue is standard:

- If the backlog is temporary, you'll catch up once volume decreases.
- If the backlog grows without bound, then of course it will not solve the issue and you will need to apply more resources. The signs should be the same as any other backlog.

Another point to be aware of is that around 250 rows/second per thread this will exceed the BigQuery quota of 100k updates/second for a table (such failures will be retried, so you might get past them anyhow). If I understand your numbers correctly, you are far from this.

Comment: Thank you for [PR #393](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/pull/393), it looks like it will avoid errors and block when I reach the 100 thread limit.

Comment: However I don't understand the fixed 100 thread limit. How can this be a relevant limit regardless of the machine type (I would think that a n1-standard-32 can handle a bit more threads than a n1-standard-1)? If it is a hard limit on BigQuery's side as [this commit](https://github.com/kennknowles/DataflowJavaSDK/commit/9a984f23d9fb05cfb014aa63ee530ece95a11389) suggests, isn't the total throughput to BigQuery dependent on the number of workers anyway?

Comment: The 100 thread limit is not highly tuned. Historically, usually fewer than 100 threads are used. This is a function of the number of rows per bundle and the size of each row. We have noted your particular use case - large bundles of large rows. Thanks!